# Load specific elements from a page with an AJAX call and append them to a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I've got two page:

**Page 1** has a title, an empty `ol` and some jQuery that calls an AJAX function.

**Page 2** has an `ol` filled with list items from which I plan on pulling specific ones.

The AJAX I'm using looks as follows:

```
$("#loader").load("ajax.html li:nth-child(1)");
```

It works great in pulling in that first `li`. However, if something is already in `#loader` it is replaced. Instead, I'd like it to append the new `li` behind the already existing ones. I've tried using the `ajax()` function but that does not allow you to call forth a specific element the way the `load()` function does, or, at least, I can't find a way.

What I'm eventually going to do is make it so that a series of `li`'s are called in via an AJAX call and added to the already-existing list. The problem is I'm getting stuck on the initial adding. The rest I'm pretty sure I can figure out by calling a function that contains a for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using $get instead of $.ajax

```
var loadContent = function(url, targetSelector, contentSelector){
   var target = $(targetSelector);
   $.get(url, function(data){
     target.append($(targetSelector, data));
   });
};

loadContent('ajax.html', '#loader', 'li:nth-child(1)');
```

You could of course skip the function definition and just do it all with the callback to $.get:

```
$.get('ajax.html', function(data){
   $('#loader').append($('li:nth-child(1)',data));
});
```

If you just want the html content of the `li` or `ol` then use `$('li:nth-child(1)',data).html()` in the append calls instead.

Comment: Works flawlessly with what I'm trying to do! Thanks very much!